# Need to assign each tuple in a list to a value in a dict

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I want to assign a value to each tuple in a list. Let's say my list looks like this:

```
[(68, 125), (113, 69), (65, 86), (108, 149), (152, 53), (78, 90), (54, 160), (20, 137), (107, 90), (48, 12)]
```

I need to assign each of these tuples into a dict where it should look like:

```
1 [(48, 12)]
2 [(68, 125), (54, 160), (20, 137)]
3 [(113, 69), (152, 53)]
4 [(108, 149)]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
new_dict = {"1":[], "2":[], "3":[], "4":[]}
for (x,y) in numbers:
    if (x,y) == (48, 12):
        new_dict += {"1:"[(x,y)]}
    elif (x,y) == (68, 125) or (x,y) == (54, 160) or (x,y) == (20, 137):
        new_dict += {"2:"[(x,y)]}
    elif (x,y) == (113, 69) or (x,y) == (152, 53):
        new_dict += {"3:"[(x,y)]}
    elif (x,y) == (108, 149):
        new_dict += {"4:"[(x,y)]}
    return new_dict
```

Help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are the tuples collected like this? What is the logic?

Comment: It is part of some homework which I have to do. I just need to know how to do this part here. I can upload the rest of this if you want but it is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code.

- iterate over the tuples, you don't have to split them
- compare using `in`, it's shorter than using `or`
- use `append` to add to an existing list

Try this:

```
new_dict = {"1":[], "2":[], "3":[], "4":[]}
for t in numbers:
    if t == (48, 12):
        new_dict["1"].append(t)
    elif t in [(68, 125), (54, 160), (20, 137)]:
        new_dict["2"].append(t)
    elif t in [(113, 69), (152, 53)]:
        new_dict["3"].append(t)
    elif t == (108, 149):
        new_dict["4"].append(t)
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [(48, 12)], '2': [(68, 125), (54, 160), (20, 137)], '4': [(108, 149)], '3': [(113, 69), (152, 53)]}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However this give me the wrong output:
    4 []
    1 []
    2 [(68, 125)]
    3 []

Comment: Sure, because it is a non generic question. But I like your answer.

Comment: 4 []
    
    1 []

    2 [(68, 125)]

    3 []

Comment: @R.Mercy The code from my answer produces the output I've included. Don't use any `return`, just try it as it is.

Comment: I tried the new edited version but it randomises the order of the values.

Comment: A dict has no order.

Comment: Is there any way to sort it

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Answer (score 1):

If you know the group of each element (as you mentioned), you can proceed with:

```
from itertools import groupby

L  = [(68, 125), (113, 69), (65, 86), (108, 149), (152, 53), (78, 90), (54, 160), (20, 137), (107, 90), (48, 12)]
ix = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]

{i:map(lambda x: x[0], g) for i, g in groupby(zip(L,ix), key=lambda x: x[1])}

Out[216]:
{1: [(68, 125)],
 2: [(113, 69), (65, 86), (108, 149)],
 3: [(152, 53), (78, 90)],
 4: [(54, 160)]}
```

Comment: again, who downvote without reading question/answers? seems common in python forum ...

Comment: User is a noobie, throwing map, zip, and groupby at her isn't going to help.  In fact, many people (myself included) absolutely hate map and zip since they are complex, so they obfuscate code, and the Python interpreter can iterate just as fast via explicit for loops.  So, I yank map and zip whenever I see them in a codebase I'm working on if at all possible - the noobs on my team will scratch heads, panic, or misinterpret what they're doing.

Comment: or do not employ noobs :) It's also by twicking these functions that people progress a little bit in programming ...

Comment: Both are valid arguments. How senior does a Python developer have to be to understand such basic functional programming?